# Cutted text in NSTableView column

Tags: swift2, nstableview, ellipsis

I'm playing a bit with NSTableView and CoreDate in Swift and all works almost ok but still can't fix an issue with cutted text in column's TableViewCell. It always shows ellipsis where text is loger than certain number of characters and I can't change it neither by setup in IB nor by changing column width and plaing with layout constraints.[see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bfUq.png)
Any hint much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution and used code line below (cell is NSTableCellView)

```
    cell.textField!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

plus addd constraints to cell text fields